# If both Train and test datasets are given in separate datasets. How to do model evaluation with train, validation, test?

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model

Generally if one dataset is given we use

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

y_pred = lr.predict(X_test)

print(confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred))

print(accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))

print(classification_report(y_test,y_pred))
```

if we are doing validation on the training dataset.

```
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

But where and how to use the test dataset in the code?

Comment: Training data has to be single dataset. Make sure that test and validation dataset have same shape

Answer (score 2):

Just to make sure that everyone is on the same page a short review what train, validation and test are good for:

- The *Train Set* is used to train a concrete model with concrete hyper-parameters
- The *Validation Set* is to measure and compare the performance of different models, especially, models that result from different hyper-parameters
- The *Test Set* is set aside and only used when you are done with training models and optimizing hyper-parameters

So in case you have all data in one dataset, you might want to do something like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
```

to get all three sets. Then you would do all the training / optimizing on `X_train,y_train` and `X_valid,y_valid` and just come back to `X_test,y_test` at the very end.

If `X_test,y_test` are already given in a separate data-set, then you can skip the first splitting part, only split into train and validation and plainly load the test-set.

I hope this answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

We are commonly using 3 main types of Data Sets when we train the Neural Network Model. **Train**, **Dev** and **Test** Set.

- Train Set is used to **train the model**.
- Dev Set (**Hold-out cross validation**) is used to evaluate trained model and **tuning the Hyperparameters** during the development process.
- Test Set is just used **measure final performance** of the final system as production level.

FYI, difference between Dev and Test sets is the Dev Sets is used on the **training the model**, instead where the Test Sets **only** used to **measure model's performance** before deployment on real project.

**Train / Dev / Test Sets Distributions**

- Train, Dev and Test sets should from **same** distribution and must be taken randomly from all the data.
- Choose Dev and Test set to **reflect** data you except to get in the future and consider important to do well.

**Size of Train, Dev and Test sets**

- Setup the size of Test sets to give **high confidence** in the overall performance of the system.
- Dev sets has to be **big enough** to evaluate different ideas.
- If your dataset is **small** one, you can separate whole data into `60 / 20 / 20` or `70 / 15 / 15` would be good.
- If your dataset is **enough to big** such as millions or hundred of millions, then you can separate whole data into `98 / 1 / 1` or `99 / 0.5 / 0.5`.

These theory is comes from one of the best Deep Learning course - DLS(Deep Learning Specialization) on Coursera.

Hope this give you intuition how to use Train / Dev / Test sets to train your system as well. Best Regards.